# Google In-App Subscriptions - Managing Pricing, Deployment and Maintenacne

Tags: android, deployment, in-app-purchase, updates, subscription

I am creating an Android application using a in-app subscription model. What is the easiest way to manage one-off Pricing, Deployment and Maintenance requests for different prices/user groups. So let me use an example to clarify my issue:

1) I launch a FREE version of an application on Google Play ($0) with in-app purchase/subscription to unlock additional functionality ($5/month). Common/Individual users go to Google Play and download the app normally.

2) Now, a large company comes along with "buying power" and says, "hey I am going to bring all my employees on your app, but can only do it for $4/month."

3) I rejoice but realize I need to change the in-app subscription price for THESE EMPLOYEES ONLY to $4. I can get their email addresses (or if there is a private deployment match).

But how do I deploy the app to these employees only at $4/month while maintaining my Google Play Store listing at $5/month. Also how does maintenance/updates work as a result if I different subscription prices for apps?

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: You should ask Google developer support for issues like this.